# Pivot-like transformation of a tibble?

Tags: r, pivot, tibble

I have a...

```
# A tibble: 6 x 10
  CCG18CD   CCG18CDH CCG18NM                      STP18CD   STP18NM           LAD18CD   LAD18NM      PCON16CD PCON16NM        Dummy
  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>                        <chr>     <chr>             <chr>     <chr>        <chr>    <chr>           <dbl>
1 E38000035 07T      NHS City and Hackney CCG     E54000029 North East London E09000001 City of Lon~ E140006~ Cities of Lond~     1
2 E38000035 07T      NHS City and Hackney CCG     E54000029 North East London E09000001 City of Lon~ E140006~ Cities of Lond~     1
3 E38000035 07T      NHS City and Hackney CCG     E54000029 North East London E09000001 City of Lon~ E140006~ Cities of Lond~     1
4 E38000035 07T      NHS City and Hackney CCG     E54000029 North East London E09000001 City of Lon~ E140006~ Cities of Lond~     1
5 E38000004 07L      NHS Barking and Dagenham CCG E54000029 North East London E09000002 Barking and~ E140005~ Barking             1
6 E38000004 07L      NHS Barking and Dagenham CCG E54000029 North East London E09000002 Barking and~ E140005~ Barking             1
```

I want to do a pivot-like transformation of the PCON16CD column, with:

```
* each distinct variable in this column/field taking a row of a new tibble

* columns generated from the variables in the current column CCG18CD

* Values being populated with a count of the column Dummy, with results shown as a percent of row total.
```

...that is, all bread and butter stuff in Excel, but a task I'm struggling to get my head round for R

Comment: habe a look at the tidyr package (Functions spread and gather).

Comment: if speed is an issue (of when dealing woith large datasets), take a look at `data.table`'s `dcast`-function